# How should I resolve this Angular node package module dependency conflict?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I just updated all my node modules using [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates).
I did this so I could install the latest version [ngx-stripe](https://ngx-stripe.dev/), which needed some updated node modules that I didn't have installed.

After updating all my node modules and then trying to install ngx-stripe I got this error below, showing me that ngx-gallery-9@1.0.6 has a peer dependency of tslib 1.10.0, which is true, but my installed version is tslib 2.5.0 in node modules.

**QUESTION** - Should I use --force or --legacy-peer-deps when running the npm install for ngx-stripe or is there something else I should try first like updating the tslib peer dependency for ngx-gallery-9?

Here is what I see:

```
➜  client git:(master) ✗ npm install ngx-stripe @stripe/stripe-js
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: ngx-gallery-9@1.0.6
npm ERR! Found: tslib@2.5.0
npm ERR! node_modules/tslib
npm ERR!   tslib@"^2.3.0" from @angular/animations@15.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/animations@"15.1.2" from @angular/platform-browser@15.1.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"15.1.2" from @angular/forms@15.1.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!         peer @angular/forms@"^11.2.11 || ^12.0.4 || ^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @zxing/ngx-scanner@3.8.0
npm ERR!         node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner
npm ERR!         2 more (ngx-bootstrap, the root project)
npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!     peer @angular/animations@"^15.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@10.2.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/ngx-bootstrap
npm ERR!       ngx-bootstrap@"^10.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   tslib@"^2.3.0" from @angular/common@15.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"15.1.2" from @angular/forms@15.1.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       peer @angular/forms@"^11.2.11 || ^12.0.4 || ^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @zxing/ngx-scanner@3.8.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner
npm ERR!         @zxing/ngx-scanner@"^3.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       2 more (ngx-bootstrap, the root project)
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from @angular/google-maps@15.1.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/google-maps
npm ERR!       @angular/google-maps@"^15.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     10 more (@angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!   20 more (@angular/compiler, @angular/compiler-cli, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer tslib@"^1.10.0" from ngx-gallery-9@1.0.6
npm ERR! node_modules/ngx-gallery-9
npm ERR!   ngx-gallery-9@"^1.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: tslib@1.14.1
npm ERR! node_modules/tslib
npm ERR!   peer tslib@"^1.10.0" from ngx-gallery-9@1.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/ngx-gallery-9
npm ERR!     ngx-gallery-9@"^1.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/charles/.npm/_logs/2023-01-27T08_58_58_320Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/charles/.npm/_logs/2023-01-27T08_58_58_320Z-debug-0.log
➜  client git:(master) ✗
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? Maybe there are some libraries that are not compatible with your Angular version yet. You can try with `--legacy-peer-deps` or check in npm web page the compatibility.

Comment: The version is the latest. Here is what I see with ng version: Angular CLI: 15.1.3
Node: 16.14.2
Package Manager: npm 9.4.0
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 15.1.2

Comment: I believe everything gets updated when I run >ncu -u using npm-check-updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is completely unrelated to `ngx-stripe`, but whenever you run `npm install`, NPM tries to fix all of its dependencies in package.json at the same time, and because you have a problem with `ngx-gallery-9`, all `npm install`s are failing. You can ignore the error for now, using `--legacy-peer-deps`, which will tell NPM to not try to deal with peer dependencies and just let you install the thing you want to install (`ngx-stripe`).

With regards to fixing the error itself, there's not much you can do here. `ngx-gallery-9` is using an older version of `tslib`, and hasn't been updated for a long time. There's currently an [open bug](https://github.com/SaeedSpate/ngx-gallery-9/issues/20) requesting that the library maintainer update his packages.

More specifically,
Angular 15 requires `tslib@"^2.3.0"`, but `ngx-gallery-9` requires `tslib@"^1.10.0"`. You can try forcing it to use the latest version by using `--legacy-peer-deps` during ALL your future npm installations, as well as running `npm install tslib@^2.3.0 --save --legacy-peer-deps` to manually choose to use the newer version, which will force the whole project to use `tslib@"^2.3.0"` and ignore `ngx-gallery-9`'s complaints, but there's a strong possibility that `ngx-gallery-9` won't work as expected.

Your best bet is to either

1. use a different gallery than `ngx-gallery-9`, or
2. Simply ignore the problem. Force everything to use `tslib@"^2.3.0"` with `npm install tslib@^2.3.0 --save --legacy-peer-deps` and hope `ngx-gallery-9` won't have any errors, or
3. downgrade Angular to an earlier version (Which is very messy, and not really recommended unless you didn't intend to be using Angular 15).

Edit:

4. Or instead undo all the changes that `npm-check-updates` did, and instead just install an older version of `ngx-stripe` that's compatible with all of your packages. `ngx-stripe` has a chart showing which version to use depending on your version of Angular, here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-stripe

Comment: I'm looking at your first option recommendation, to not use ngx-gallery-9 and possibly just use ngx-gallery. I'm not sure why I used the library ngx-gallery-9 instead of it's root library ngx-gallery, I'm currently looking to see if ngx-gallery is not compatible with the latest versions of Angular 13+. Maybe that's why I didn't initially use it or but maybe it will help my issue. I didn't really have a strong reason to upgrade to Angular 15. I just ran npm-check-updates and updated all packages. I was on Angular 13 before.

Comment: I took your advice and found another package: https://ngx-gallery.netlify.app/#/lightbox

Answer (score 0):

Just type: 
`npm install ngx-stripe @stripe/stripe-js --force`
or `npm install ngx-stripe @stripe/stripe-js--legacy-peer-deps`